# Gradle "xxxxxxxx" project refresh failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Please can someone help me with this issue im just now trying to mess with android studio once setup i create a project i get nothing in Src folder sry i cant post photos yet :-(

the main issue i believe is this :

> Gradle 'MyApplication2' project refresh failed: Could not execute
>   build using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-rc-3-bin.zip'.
>   Initialization script
>   'C:\Users\D'Angelo\AppData\Local\Temp\wrap1569786557313452312.gradle'
>   line: 4 Could not compile initialization script
>   'C:\Users\D'Angelo\AppData\Local\Temp\wrap1569786557313452312.gradle'.
>   Could not compile initialization script
>   'C:\Users\D'Angelo\AppData\Local\Temp\wrap1569786557313452312.gradle'.
>   startup failed: initialization script
>   'C:\Users\D'Angelo\AppData\Local\Temp\wrap1569786557313452312.gradle':
>   4: unexpected char: '\' @ line 4, column 38. new
>   File('C:\Users\D'Angelo\AppData\Local\Temp\wrap1787089259123077767loc').write
>   wrapperPropertyFileLocation

happens when i try to sync project with gradle files

Any help would be greatly appreciated!.

Comment: What is your Android Studio version? 0.37? 0.40?

Comment: i just upgraded to 0.40 hoping it would make a difference but i installed as low as 0.30 and still the same issue

Comment: post your build.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: i dont know if thats how its suppose to be but when i open my project there are to "build.gradle" files...One is completely empty and the other has this " compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'" im not sure where gradle-wrapper.properties are again this is new to me i apologize.

Comment: Please post more information on your project including your build.gradle file. You shouldn't be using Gradle 1.9rc3; I'm not sure where that version spec came from.

Comment: thats the thing my build.gradle file is empty and im not sure where the 1.9 came from either

Comment: Maybe this could have something to do with it?
https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1141